# SQL QUERY TO TRAVERSE DATA

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table as mentioned below

```
COLUMN_NAME OLD_VALUE   NEW_VALUE
:-----      :-------    :------------
FRST_NM     MICHAEL     TEST
LST_NM      DAVIS       TEST_IQVIA
MID_NM      AUSTIN      TEST
```

I have used the SQL as mentioned below

```
       select 
     (  case when COLUMN_NAME = 'FRST_NM' then NVL2 (new_value , new_value  ,  old_value )  else NULL  end )  FRST_NM,
      (  case when COLUMN_NAME = 'LST_NM' then NVL2 (new_value , new_value  ,  old_value )  else NULL end )  LST_NM,
         (  case when COLUMN_NAME = 'MID_NM' then NVL2 (new_value , new_value  ,  old_value )  else NULL end )  MID_NM
         from TEST_TABLE
```

Getting output like the mentioned below .

```
FRST_NM  LST_NM       MID_NM 
:------- :--------    :----------
TEST     NULL         NULL
NULL     TEST_IQVIA   NULL
NULL     NULL         TEST
```

The expected output would be

```
FRST_NM  LST_NM       MID_NM 
:------  :-------     :-------
TEST     TEST_IQVIA   TEST
```

Could anyone please guide me

Comment: What about `select max(<expression>)`? Also `nvl2(expr1, expr1, expr2)` is equal to `nvl(expr1, expr2)`, but takes more time to write and understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use aggregation:

```
select max(case when COLUMN_NAME = 'FRST_NM' then coalesce(new_value, old_value) end) as FRST_NM,
       max(case when COLUMN_NAME = 'LST_NM' then coalesce(new_value, old_value ) end)  as LST_NM,
       max(case when COLUMN_NAME = 'MID_NM' then coalesce(new_value, old_value) end) as  MID_NM
from TEST_TABLE;
```

Notes:

- `nvl2()` is not appropriate here.  Although you could use `nvl()`, you might as well use the SQL standard function `coalesce()`.
- `else null` is redundant -- `NULL` is the default value.

Comment: I got the output as per requirement , Many thanks :)

Comment: Hii , this SQL is giving only one row from the table which is max , I have many rows in the table and the SQL is fetching only one row. Which is the MAX.

Comment: My bad , i missed the group by :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pivot columns like below :

```sql
select *
from your_table
pivot(
max(nvl(NEW_VALUE, OLD_VALUE)) for COLUMN_NAME in (
    'FRST_NM' as FRST_NM
  , 'LST_NM' as LST_NM
  , 'MID_NM' as MID_NM
  )
)
;
```